# Normal of a plane- converting parametric equation to general equation

Tags: vectors

> Which one of the following is a normal vector of the plane $\mathbf x=s(1,2,3)+t(2,3,4)$ where $s,t\in\mathbb R$? 
>  $\begin{align}&(a) \ (3,5,7) \phantom{XXXXXXXXXX} & (c)  \ \ \ \ (1,2,1) \\
> &(b) \ 20 \phantom{XXXXXXXXXX} & (d)  \ (1,-2,1) 
> \end{align}$

To find the normal of the plane I need to find the coefficient of the general equation, right?
However I am not sure how to do that in this case. This is what I have

$$x= 1s + 2t $$

$$y= 2s + 3t$$

$$z=3s + 4t$$

so by cancelling each one out I get

$$y-2x = -t$$
and

$$z+4(y-2x)=3s$$

... But how can I simplify this to get the general equation??

Answer (score 6):

The answer is (d). Parametric equations are $$x=s+2t,\quad y=2s+3t,\quad z=3s+4t.$$
From the first two equations we have
$t=2x-y$ and $s=2y-3x$. Substituting these into the third equation we get the equation of the plane $x-2y+z=0$ and hence the normal vector is $(1, -2, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Any point in the plane  is a linear combination of $u = (1,2,3)$ and $v= (2,3,4)$. In fact these vectors belong to the plane, so why not take their cross product $u \times v= (-1,2,-1)$. This is the normal to the plane. But so is any scalar multiple of it, namely $-(-1,2,-1)=(1,-2,1)$ which is answer (d). Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

A vector will be a normal vector to the plane if and only if it's perpendicular to both $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,3,4)$, because those two directions are parallel to the plane, and they aren't parallel to each other. Of the multiple choices, (d) is the only one with this property.